# Searching for exact wording of a quote about a father living two lives, his own and that of his son

Tags: quote-source

[edited]
I remember it from decades ago when I was into reading quotation collections. I interpreted it as meaning how a father might see himself in his son and guide him away from certain experiences and toward others, accepting some merit/blame on how his son's life unfolds.

I searched via Google and a couple other engines - nada.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some details and context, please? Where do you think you heard it? Was it in a book? Was it about a person? What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: @CDR I made an edit per your request.

Comment: HI and welcome to Literature SE. References to ChatGPT tend to be [poorly received here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1824/289). Since large language models emit plausible words without worrying about factual accuracy, [references from ChatGPT would not be reliable](https://blogs.library.duke.edu/blog/2023/03/09/chatgpt-and-fake-citations/) anyway. Hence, using ChatGPT as a source is assumed to indicate that the question is too poorly researched be taken seriously. To ward off downvotes, you might want to edit (again!) to remove the mention of ChatGPT. Good luck!

Comment: While your question isn't an identification request per se, please also take a look at the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification-requests and see if you can add further details to the question based on the suggestions there. The more details, the better: where did you tend to read books of quotations? How many decades, specifically? Was the quotation from a poem, or was it prose? Hope these suggestions help!

Comment: Hi, @verbose.  Thanks for the tips.  When researching I self-rate the reliability of sources then verify if necessary.  I generally start with Google but to omit AGI in spite of its limitations seems short-sited if the goal is to find leads.  I completely agree with not taking its 'word' for anything as I've caught it in a series of lies although they have improved it.  Anyway, that's all I can remember about the quote.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for but maybe someone will find it interesting: "Basically, we all live three lives: our life, the life of our parents, and that of our children. Events within our experience, particularly our youth, remain the most visceral in memory, but events that lie beyond the horizon of these generations tend to be more abstract“
--Leon Levy, The Mind of Wall Street, 2002